# Unable to understand array behaviour

Tags: c#, arrays

Try:

```
Array[] UserInformation;
UserInformation[0] = "Test";
```

but i get a error `Cannot implicitly convert string to System.Array`

But this works:

```
string[] asp;
asp[0] = "ram";
```

I don't want to use `string[]` or `int[]` because I have to assign different data types in each index.

If its not the right way to add items to an array please suggest the correct way?

Comment: Your first one can't work because you're declaring an array of arrays. Your second one can't work because it's not initialized. If you need to group different types of items together you'll probably want a different data structure.

Comment: How is that related to asp.net? Is Asp.net in your eyes using a different runtime than winforms on that level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) is a type that exists in the BCL - you are looking for an `object` array, which you also need to initialize:

```
object[] UserInformation = new object[10];
UserInformation[0] = "Test";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Array[] UserInformation;
```

This declares `UserInformation` as an array of arrays... A string is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an array of "object", since everything in C# inherits from that base class.

```
object[] anArray = new object[];
```